# Табель учета рабочего времени php и mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть необходимость перенести табель учета рабочего времени сотрудников из экселя на сайт, используя php и mysql. 
Табель имеет следующий вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столкнулся с двумя вопросами: 
 1. как реализовать таблицу базы данных; 
2. как организовать ввод данных в эту таблицу;

Отправным пунктом выбрал для себя такую реализацию: 
1. Структура БД: 
employee_id (ai); 
tab_employee_id (Табельный номер); 
employee_name (ФИО); 
employee_post (Должность); 
year (Год); 
month (Месяц); 
day (День); 
value (Отработано часов)

2. Одним из вариантов ввода данных предлагают использовать ajax для моментального сохранения отредактированной ячейки.

Отрисовывать скелет страницы для каждого месяца вручную? А как создавать страницы для каждого месяца? через ?year=2022&month=1

Быть может, кто то сталкивался с подобными задачами

Comment: вопрос желательно разделить на несколько, чтобы по каждому можно было дать конкретный ответ. В противном случае его могут закрыть, по той причине, что он слишком общий.

Comment: Я делал похожую штуку. Структура таблицы табеля: user_id, date, value. А на фронте был vue.js + vuex который ходил в php через axios. Чтобы рисовать саму форму с табелем еще использовал moment.js для удобной работы с датами на клиенте.